# implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'

Tags: java, android

I have occurred the above-mentioned error and I could not find any answer from the internet as well as several books. If anyone can give me a solution, it will be very helpful for me to make my SQLite database

classes.dex
Type com.readystatesoftware.android.sqliteassethelper.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: C:\Users...gradle\caches\transforms-3\b2257b2869a3735d41009b6b49890d4f\transformed\jetified-sqliteassethelper-2.0.1\classes.dex, C:\Users..\Desktop\Android-App\Assets_DB\app\build\intermediates\external_file_lib_dex_archives\debug\0_jetified-sqliteassethelper-2.0.1.jar:classes.dex
com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: C:\Users\Hayder.gradle\caches\transforms-3\b2257b2869a3735d41009b6b49890d4f\transformed\jetified-sqliteassethelper-2.0.1\classes.dex
com.android.tools.r8.internal.b: Type com.readystatesoftware.android.sqliteassethelper.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: C:\Users\Hayder.gradle\caches\transforms-3\b2257b2869a3735d41009b6b49890d4f\transformed\jetified-sqliteassethelper-2.0.1\classes.dex, C:\Users\Hayder\Desktop\Android-App\Assets_DB\app\build\intermediates\external_file_lib_dex_archives\debug\0_jetified-sqliteassethelper-2.0.1.jar:classes.dex

public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Engin.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
String sqlTables;

public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
```

}

```
public Cursor getEmployees() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String [] sqlSelect = {"REG_NUMBER"};
    sqlTables = "EngineDetail_Table";

    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
            null, null, null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;

}
```

}

Here is MainActivity.java class

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private Cursor regNumbers;
private MyDatabase db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    db = new MyDatabase(this);
    regNumbers = db.getEmployees(); // you would not typically call this on the main thread
    Log.d("Reg Numbers" , regNumbers.getString(Integer.parseInt("REG_NUMBER")));

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    regNumbers.close();
    db.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like you've included the library twice in your project. Have a look at `build.gradle` `dependencies` and check that you don't have it coming from two different sources (e.g. maven dependency and a plain jar file).

Comment: dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation files('libs/sqliteassethelper-2.0.1.jar')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])}

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.assets_db/com.example.assets_db.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> implementation files('libs/sqliteassethelper-2.0.1.jar')
> implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

This includes the jar twice from libs. It's not an error but redundant anyway.

> implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'

This includes the library from a maven repository.

Either delete the jar file in libs and its `implementation` dependency, or delete the maven `implementation` dependency.

Comment: this one maven dependency   buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

Comment: The maven dependency is the `implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'`